# EmberJS - Populating a model via a remote JSON api

Tags: javascript, json, api, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to populate an emberJS model via results from a remote API (http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/).

The request string is https://api.themoviedb.org//3/movie/popular?api_key={{KEY}}

It returns records in this format:

```
{"page":1,"results":[{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/8aZHR0wXacn5DVYK3cS2ozWYPCN.jpg","id":64686,"original_title":"47 Ronin","release_date":"2013-12-25","poster_path":"/v9JCVROrdlHZCWP3D6pnV8Xc29w.jpg","popularity":97.4338866047715,"title":"47 Ronin","vote_average":6.4,"vote_count":78}],"total_pages":7834,"total_results":156677}
```

This gets recent popular movies.

I have a model set up

```
App.Movie = DS.Model.extend({
    title: null
});
```

So far I've been using fixtures but now I want to be able to pull in data from the API and populate it that way.

I've had a look at a few examples but I can't seem to get my head around it (apologies, I'm relatively new to Ember and backend in general)

Comment: Heres a prettier version of that JSON for you all: http://jsfiddle.net/A27Ct/

Comment: How are you making the request? In the model of the route?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd do something like this

```
store.createRecord('movie', {
    title: json_response.original_title
});
```

where store is your DS.Store

Answer (score 0):

I think your model should be this:

```
App.Movie = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

You also need to setup the deserialization since, if I am not mistaken, the REST adapter expects the format to be:

```
{ "movie": { 
      "page" : 1,
      ...
   }
}
```